# Qt QSpinBox with a set of predefined values

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I have a `QSpinBox` which should only accept a set of discrete values (let's say 2, 5, 10). I can `setMinimum(2)` and `setMaximum(10)`, but I cannot `setSingleStep` because I have a step of 3 and one of 5.

Is there a different widget which I can use, but which has the same UI as the `QSpinBox`?

If not, what should I overwrite to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Your question means that the spinbox has from 2 to 10 but if you use it ,it shows 2,5,10 every step?Is there some regulations for the subtraction? 3,5, and next?

Comment: Fair question, I am sorry if it was not clear. I want the spin box to only allow selection of 2, 5 and 10. Nothing in between. If the value is 5 and I press up, I want to go to 10. If the value is 5 and I want to go down, the value should go to 2. Inserting 3 manually should go up or down to the nearest available value.

Comment: Ok, I understand,I'm sorry.

Comment: Why don't use just use a [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qcombobox.html) instead? This will allow you to just have [2, 5, 10] as the values. Otherwise, you'd have to make your own QWidget to mimic what you want.

Comment: It must look and behave just as a `QSpinBox`, cannot have a dropdown unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QSpinBox::stepsBy()` to handle the values.

For example:

```
class Spinbox: public QSpinBox
{
public:
    Spinbox(): QSpinBox()
    {
        acceptedValues << 0 << 3 << 5 << 10; // We want only 0, 3, 5, and 10
        setRange(acceptedValues.first(), acceptedValues.last());

    }
    virtual void stepBy(int steps) override
    {
        int const index = std::max(0, (acceptedValues.indexOf(value()) + steps) % acceptedValues.length()); // Bounds the index between 0 and length
        setValue(acceptedValues.value(index));
    }
private:
    QList<int> acceptedValues;
};
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Simple and straightforward. Thank you!

Comment: How is this integrated into the project and instantiated in QML?